# Taking the last four characters of an charachter array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have

```
TCHAR szPIDKEY[255];//for product id
 DWORD dwLen = sizeof(szPIDKEY)/sizeof(szPIDKEY[0]); //calculating the size of the key
UINT res = MsiGetProperty(hInstall, _T("PIDKEY"), szPIDKEY, &dwLen); 
if(res != ERROR_SUCCESS) 
{
    //fail the installation 
    return 1; 
}
```

the key string looks like xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx, i want to take only the last four xxxx in TCHAR , how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
 #ifndef UNICODE  
 typedef std::string String 
 #else
 typedef std::wstring String 
 #endif

String szKey = szPIDKEY;
size_t found = szKey.find_last_of("-");
String szFind = szKey.substr (found,4);
```

Comment: You can also do `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> String;`

Comment: `TString` seems like a better name.

Answer (score 0):

Is this really so hard?

```
TCHAR lastFour[5] /* 4 + 1 for null terminator */
_tcscpy(lastFour, szPIDKEY + dwLen - 4); /* copy the last four characters and 
                                        null terminator */
```

If you want to do strings the C way, then you are going to have to learn how to do pointer manipulations like the above. `szPIDKEY` is an array, but it also functions as a pointer to the first element of the array, `szPIDKEY + dwLen` is then a pointer to the last character of the key (the null terminator). So `szPIDKEY + dwLen - 4` is a pointer to four characters before that.

Untested code.

Comment: If you'd like your answers to be upvoted, you should probably drop the "Is this really so hard ?" line which brings nothing but really makes you look pedantic.

Comment: @ereOn: I guess I'm trying to get the OP to think for herself. I've seen a few of her questions, she seems good enough to answer a question like this for herself. No offense meant.

Comment: Well, sure. But not everybody has the context or knows the OP. I'm just saying that if I was relunctant to upvote this answer because of that line, others might do the same. Whatever the original intent.

Answer (score 0):

TCHAR is nothing else but a char if UNICODE is not defined and wchar if it is defined. So if you want to take the last 4 symbols you may treat is as you would have treated these types.

So maybe you should do something like:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#include <wchar.h>
int get_len(TCHAR[] val) {
  return wcslen(val);
}
#else 
#include <cstring>
int get_len(TCHAR[] val) {
  return strlen(val);
}
#endif
```

EDIT: In fact there is a function already defined in windows that does what I described above and it is _tcslen (thanks to jajjaj for this one). However I decided to leave the code above so that you get the idea what it does.

And then using the function above you have the last 4 characters stored in

> szPIDKEY[_tcslen(szPIDKEY-4)], ...szPIDKEY[_tcslen(szPIDKEY-1)]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Windows already has a function `_tcslen` that does exactly what you do above.

Comment: @jahhaj cool! Thank you! I will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: C++ supports overloading. `int get_len(WCHAR[])` and `int get_len(char[])` can co-exist, and the compiler will automatically select the right one. The Windows API itself is C, and therefore can't support such overloading, but that's not a problem here.